# Loading SpriteKit scene on background thread causes app to crash because of memory issues

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, sprite-kit

I'm having this strange problem.  In my game I load a Scene from an .sks file.  When I load it on the main thread I have no issues whatsoever.  Everything loads just fine.  But when I load on the background thread, the app crashes due to memory issues.  Here's my code...

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let nextScene = World(fileNamed: "GameScene")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.nextScene = nextScene
            self.playerRunningState = .RUNNINGRIGHT
        }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would work on the main thread but not on a background thread.

FYI it crashes on the following line:

```
let nextScene = World(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

Comment: Please post your world class since this is where your problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit is not thread safe when manipulating nodes as quoted in Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode

> Manipulations to nodes must occur in the main thread. All of the SpriteKit callbacks for SKViewDelegate, SKSceneDelegate and SKScene occur in the main thread and these are safe places to make manipulations to nodes. However, if you are performing other work in the background, you should adopt an approach similar to Listing 1.

All manipulations must happen on the main thread synchronously, and making a new node is a manipulation. If you wan to make manipulations to nodes off of the main thread then you must adopt this approach:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global()

    var makeNodeModifications = false

    func backgroundComputation() {
        queue.async {
            // Perform background calculations but do not modify 
            // SpriteKit objects

            // Set a flag for later modification within the 
            // SKScene or SKSceneDelegate callback of your choosing

            self.makeNodeModifications = true
        }
    }
}
extension ViewController: SKSceneDelegate {
    func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval, for scene: SKScene) {
        if makeNodeModifications {
            makeNodeModifications = false

            // Make node modifications
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a node in a background thread is not manipulating it. You can create all the nodes you want in background threads, you just need to make sure they are finished before you throw them in the game to be processed by the update loop. He is creating a node in a background thread, then manipulating during the main thread, which is permissible. If I had to guess, something is going on in the init of World that is doing manipulation of a node, which is causing his problems.

Comment: When you are initializing a Scene from a file it is considered a manipulation and is not controlled by the programmer but instead by the SpriteKit system

Comment: Says who? Loading from a file is just unarchiving it and going through the coder init.

Comment: I use background loading to prepare my scenes white the player is going through the main menu setup to avoid loading times,  there was no threading issues because the scene was not being processed by the engine yet.

Comment: When SpriteKit loads a scene from a file it uses a coder. and in every nodes coder initializer it sets all the variables of the nodes to what was set in the sks file.

Comment: Were you loading the file from the sks file or a class?

Comment: I use sks files. Keep design separate from function. Sks files are just NSKeyedArchived files of your scene.  One of the easiest ways to make turn based games is to archive your scene and send it to the cloud.  Now you definitely do not want to be doing networking on your main thread.

Comment: The reason you do manipulations on main thread is because you do not know what is going to happen and when the dispatcher is going to switch threads.  You could be in the middle of lets say a physics calculation, and a background thread fires that removes the node it was trying to calculate. Boom you now have undesired behavior.  But creating a node is no different than creating any other instance of an object.  It is just memory, nothing is being utilized yet.

Comment: so your using the coder data directly with NSKeyedArchived or indirectly with (filenamed: )?

Comment: Indirectly. `SKScene(fileNamed:”GameScene”)`